# Marginal PDF from Joint PDF of two Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, geometric-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent Geometric distributions with the parameter '$p$'.
$$Z = X+Y$$
$$W=X-Y$$
Now I have found the joint PDF as below:
$P_{Z,W}(i,j)=p^2(1-p)^{i-2}$ for   $i>0$, $-i<j<i$ , $i+j$ is even here is my question: How can I find the marginal PDF for $W$?
I know I should let $Z\to\infty$ somehow, but I'm not sure how to proceed doing so.

Comment: If you _plot_ the values of $i$ and $j$ where the joint pdf is nonzero on the plane, it will become obvious how you can get the marginal pdfs.